# Where's this lighthouse in the USA?

Tags: identify-this

[image][image]

My grandma painted this at least twenty years ago around, but she can't remember where. She remembers this is a famous beach. I accidentally threw it out when we were renovating her house, and this is the only photo we have. She's pretty pissed off, and I want to give her an answer. We're all American, and we're pretty sure she did it in the U.S.

I know this might be a stretch.  We have a hard time narrowing locations down because my grandma and grandpa lived in most states on the U.S. East and West Coasts.

Comment: I wonder if anyone with Photoshop skills can transform the picture to how it would appear face on?

Comment: Reminds me of the [Key West lighthouse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Key_West_Lighthouse), which from some angles would look like it's surrounded by trees like that.

Comment: I tried to unskew it with GraphicConverter, but I obviously misjudged the horizontal angle.  Reverse image search failed to find even something similar.

Answer (score 8):

Might be the **Ponce Park Lighthouse** (AKA [**Ponce de Leon Inlet Light**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ponce_de_Leon_Inlet_Light)):

[image]
<sup>Source: ErgoSum88, Public domain, via [Wikimedia Commons](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Ponce_Inlet_Lighthouse_02.jpg)</sup>

[image]
<sup>Source: Fl295 on English Wikipedia, Public domain, via [Wikimedia Commons](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/2b/Ponce_inlet.jpg)</sup>

But there are other lighthouses which are quite similar, too. For example the [**Currituck Beach Light**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currituck_Beach_Light):

[image]
<sup>Source: Lago Mar, [CC BY-SA 4.0](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0), via [Wikimedia Commons](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Currituck_Beach_Lighthouse_Corolla.jpg)</sup>

[image]
<sup>Source: Mattikai, [CC BY-SA 4.0](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0), via [Wikimedia Commons](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Currituckbeachlight.jpg)</sup>

I fear it's almost impossible to tell exactly which lighthouse is shown on the painting. From the [35 red lighthouses in the USA listed on Wikimedia Commons](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Category:Red_lighthouses_in_the_United_States) (Currituck isn't mentioned in that list), it might also be:

- [**Jupiter Inlet Light**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jupiter_Inlet_Light):

  [image]
  <sup>Source: Ebyabe, [CC BY-SA 3.0](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0), via [Wikimedia Commons](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Jupiter_Inlet_FL_Lighthouse02.jpg)</sup>
- [**Little Sable Light**](http://Little%20Sable%20Point%20Light):

  [image]
  <sup>Source: Joe Ross from Lansing, Michigan, CC BY-SA 2.0, via [Wikimedia Commons](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Little_Sable_Point_Lighthouse_(3802210254).jpg)</sup>

Comment: As soon as I saw it I thought Ponce.